# twinapi.appcore.dll faulting module in background task

Tags: uwp, background-task

I have created the UWP application and tested in various environments. In some machines it suddenly got crashed. In the event viewer we have found the logs as

> Faulting application name: backgroundTaskHost.exe, version: 10.0.17723.1000, time stamp: 0x6fe3727f
>   Faulting module name: twinapi.appcore.dll, version: 10.0.17723.1000, time stamp: 0xbc2611b9
>   Exception code: 0xc000027b

Comment: In order to help with this question, we would need to know the callstack of the exception and/or the repro code. Ideally both.